# How to redirect based on the type of model in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on a new rails 3 application. In this application I have 2 different types of resources(**admin** and **garage**) both with different views and with 2 different login screens using devise. The admin can create a garage and can generate a password for the garage using which the garage manager can login to the application. Till now I am able to implement this.

One problem that I am facing in the above implementation is that the garage manager, once logged in, is able to view the admin section by changing the url in the browser and can make changes like an admin user.

Now what I am trying to implement is to have a single log in/sign in form for both the models and when someone logs in, depending on their model type they should be redirected to their respective views. Also, I would like to restrict all the users but admin from using the admin section.

What should be my approach to implement this. I am using devise for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resource` is an instance of one of your models here:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
  return admin_route_path  if resource.is_a?(Admin)
  return garage_route_path if resource.is_a?(Garage)
end
```

`resource` is a symbol of the model name here:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  return "/admin" if resource == :admin
  return "/"      if resource == :garage
end
```

Normally goes in `application_controller.rb`

---

> One problem that I am facing in the above implementation is that the garage manager, once logged in, is able to view the admin section by changing the url in the browser and can make changes like an admin user.

As for this, it's an authorization problem and not an authentication problem. Though you can do some simple stuff within devise to manage this, like an admin flag or something of that nature so you can differentiate the two. Just redirecting won't solve this issue entirely.

Take a look at cancan, declarative authorization and I'm sure there are many others.